# WeakReference and the Scala REPL

Tags: scala, console, weak-references

I would like to play with [scala.ref.WeakReference](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/ref/WeakReference.html). However, before trying to implement the big thing, I would like to try to check the behavior in scala console. I tried a few thing but I was unable to obtained my object to be dereferenced. Here is one of my tries:

```
> class A
defined class A

> class B(var value: A)
defined class B

> new B(new A)
res0: B = B@c8aeb3

> new scala.ref.WeakReference(res0.value)
res1: scala.ref.WeakReference[A] = scala.ref.WeakReferenceWithWrapper@16a5d72

> res0.value = new A

> res1.get // Here I hope to get None
res3: Option[A] = Some(A@135707c)
```

Another try is given by oxbow_lakes below.

I've also tried to explicitly run the garbage collector (calling `java.lang.System.gc`) in vain.

Is there any way to dereference the content of `res1` ?

Comment: As you can see, we're highly confused about what the REPL does, what the REPL says it's doing, and what the REPL is supposed to be doing, and when the GC will skip collecting the unreferenced object. Is there any chance you can write a 
Scala script in a **file** that tests the behavior you want, and see if that works, so you don't have to worry about the vagaries of how the REPL prints its result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_22).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> class A  
defined class A

scala> class B(var value: A)
defined class B

scala> new B(new A)
res0: B = B@4223d9b

scala> new scala.ref.WeakReference(res0.value)
res1: scala.ref.WeakReference[A] = scala.ref.WeakReferenceWithWrapper@20eb607d

scala> res0.value = new A

scala> System gc

scala> res1 get
res3: Option[A] = None
```

By the way, if I run it as a script without an explicit `System gc`, it won’t delete the reference either. So to me it’s not an issue of the REPL but just the way that weak references and the garbage collector work.

Comment: +1: It's definitely an REPL quirk. Your solution just makes it so the REPL doesn't keep a direct reference to the first value of the `var` that I pointed out in my answer. But the REPL is going to keep a direct reference to the **second** value you gave `res0.value`, so you haven't completely solved the problem for experimentation in general.

Comment: Well, I just followed the original question…

Comment: It is not keeping a reference to `res0.value` because the assignment `res0.value = new A` returns `()`. The REPL never sees it actually. If it keeps a reference, it will show you so in the result string.

Comment: If one wants to be sure that no spurious references are kept, one should wrap the code inside some `{‌`‌`}` construct.

Comment: When you ask the REPL to run `b = new A` it actually runs `b = new A; val synthvar$0 = res0.value`. It uses this to print the result of the assignment statement, which it displays as `b :A = A@92524b0`. (Yes, I'm using 2.8.1.final.)

Comment: You're right. The REPL does something different for `res0.value = new A` than it does for `b = new A`. In the `res0.value` case, it doesn't keep a reference. The closure solution is unnecessary (for now at least).

Comment: @oxbow_lakes may be it's too late to be relevant, but `System gc` is done on a "best-effort" basis, so it might not have actually run. Just my two cents

Answer (score 1):

Run your code with `scala -Xprint:parser` and you'll see what's keeping old value of a `var` referenced even after you reassign it.

I'm going to simplify things here, and just run two lines of code:

```
var b=1
b=2
```

And this is what Scala prints:

```
scala> var b=1
[[syntax trees at end of parser]]// Scala source: <console>
package <empty> {
  object line2$object extends scala.ScalaObject {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    object $iw extends scala.ScalaObject {
      def <init>() = {
        super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      object $iw extends scala.ScalaObject {
        def <init>() = {
          super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        var b = 1                                ///// YOUR CODE HERE
      }
    }
  }
}

[[syntax trees at end of parser]]// Scala source: <console>
package <empty> {                                /////THIS IS AN object
                                                 /////SO PRESUMABLY IT CAN'T BE GC'ED
  object RequestResult$line2$object extends scala.ScalaObject {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    lazy val scala_repl_value = {                 /////THIS LAZY VAL
      scala_repl_result;                          /////WILL REFERENCE THE OLD VALUE
      line2$object.$iw.$iw.b                      /////EVEN AFTER YOU REASSIGN THE var
    };
    val scala_repl_result: String = {
      line2$object.$iw.$iw;
      "".$plus("b: Int = ").$plus(scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime.stringOf(line2$object.$iw.$iw.b))
    }
  }
}

b: Int = 1

scala> b=2
[[syntax trees at end of parser]]// Scala source: <console>
package <empty> {
  object line3$object extends scala.ScalaObject {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    object $iw extends scala.ScalaObject {
      def <init>() = {
        super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      import line2$object.$iw.$iw.b;              ///// I DON'T THINK THIS (ORDINARILY ILLEGAL)
                                                  ///// import CONTRIBUTES TO THE PROBLEM
      object $iw extends scala.ScalaObject {
        def <init>() = {
          super.<init>();
          ()
        };
        b = 2;                                    /////YOUR CODE HERE
        val synthvar$0 = b
      }
    }
  }
}

[[syntax trees at end of parser]]// Scala source: <console>
package <empty> {
  object RequestResult$line3$object extends scala.ScalaObject {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    lazy val scala_repl_value = {
      scala_repl_result;
      line3$object.$iw.$iw.synthvar$0
    };
    val scala_repl_result: String = {
      line3$object.$iw.$iw;
      "".$plus("b: Int = ").$plus(line3$object.$iw.$iw.synthvar$0).$plus("\012")
    }
  }
}

b: Int = 2
```

---

*EDIT:* To add on to [Debilski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4398825/weakreference-and-the-scala-repl/4400019#4400019), I think the following solution will let you reassign the variable as many times as you want without the REPL keeping a reference to the old value:

```
class A
class B{
   var _value:A = new A
   def value = _value
   def pleaseUpdate( closure: B => Unit ) = closure(this)
}
```

Define your container object as:

```
val b=new B
```

And whenever you want to update the variable that's inside it:

```
b.pleaseUpdate( _._value = new A )
```

Comment: I can't tell from this, but IIRC when Scala builds a closure over a var it boxes it in a mutable form and everything references the box.  That way all the different references see the same updates to the value of the var.  So if it's capturing the var I think it would prevent collection of the box despite setting the var to null but not the object it references.  But it's been a while since I've looked at that in depth...

Comment: @Erik: I guess it depends when `scala_repl_value` is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

My idea was to use a `var` explicitly and set to `null`:

```
scala> var b = new B(new A)
b: B = B@45033fb5

scala> new scala.ref.WeakReference(b.value)
res0: scala.ref.WeakReference[A] = scala.ref.WeakReferenceWithWrapper@6a7be687

scala> b = null
b: B = null

scala> res0.get
res1: Option[A] = Some(A@79f71773)
```

It still does not work, though: the REPL is presumably doing stuff under the covers which keeps hold of the reference. I would therefore not advise using it to test the use of `Reference`s.

Comment: It was one of the other tries. It does not work either. I'm also afraid that the REPL keeps obscure reference to the objects.

Comment: Yes - my tests revealed the same. I've kept the answer in for completeness

Answer (score 0):

From Java API docs:

> Calling the gc method suggests that
>   the Java Virtual Machine expend effort
>   toward recycling unused objects in
>   order to make the memory they
>   currently occupy available for quick
>   reuse. When control returns from the
>   method call, the Java Virtual Machine
>   has made a best effort to reclaim
>   space from all discarded objects.

In my anecdotal experience this means it rarely triggers a truly complete collection, especially if there is no pressure in terms of available memory.  If you put pressure on it, it will be collected.  I think you're expecting for more deterministic behavior out of the GC than it provides.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.8.0.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_22).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> var s = new String("Hello, world!")         
s: java.lang.String = Hello, world!

scala> import scala.ref.WeakReference
import scala.ref.WeakReference

scala> val w = new WeakReference(s)  
w: scala.ref.WeakReference[java.lang.String] = scala.ref.WeakReferenceWithWrapper@663f3fbd

scala> s = null
s: java.lang.String = null

scala> Array.ofDim[Byte](1024*1024)
res1: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
scala> Array.ofDim[Byte](1024*1024)
res2: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
scala> Array.ofDim[Byte](1024*1024)
res3: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
scala> Array.ofDim[Byte](1024*1024)
res4: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
scala> Array.ofDim[Byte](1024*1024)
res5: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
scala> Array.ofDim[Byte](1024*1024)
res6: Array[Byte] = Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, ...
scala> System.gc

scala> var g = w.get
g: Option[java.lang.String] = None
```

Comment: Huh??? Either my answer's wrong or your answer's wrong. Take a look at mine and tell me what I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: I take that back. The `lazy val` that's keeping the old value referenced (in my answer) was added in commit 20631 which appears to be in 2.8.1, but not 2.8.0.

Comment: I can see the same behaviour (as Erik) in 2.7.7, 2.8.0 and 2.8.1. (Although the WeakReference would already be deleted in 2.7.7 without a `System.gc` – but that might have be a coincidence.)

Comment: There's a lot of non-determinism involved here.  Did anyone copy&paste my transcript into a 2.8.1 REPL?  I don't have time at the moment to go through the install.

Comment: You're right. Even in 2.8.1, the variable was deleted, even though `-Xprint:parser` seems to show that it's keeping a reference. I'm not sure I understand what's going on anymore.

Comment: @Debilski - I wasn't sure if you used the same stuff or something comparable.  Since we're talking about subtle behaviors I thought it was best to make sure.

Comment: Okay, I must confess, I skipped the Array stuff. Calling `System gc` was enough in all cases.

Comment: @Debilsky - I had to add the array stuff to get it to work on my machine, and I had to fiddle with the number of times I did it and the size of the arrays in order to make it give the desired result.